# Eliminar bordes de bitmap c#

Tags: c#, bitmap

Tengo un bitmap al cual relleno de color blanco de la siguiente forma

```
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(50, 50);
            using (Graphics graph = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                Rectangle ImageSize = new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50);
                graph.FillRectangle(Brushes.White,ImageSize);
            }
```

Sin embargo, cuando lo guardo siempre me queda con el siguiente borde negro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo eliminar dichos bordes?

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a stack overflow en español, te invito a terminar [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y puedas obtener tu primer medalla.

Comment: ¿Podrias colocar tu código completo? ¿En que version de .NET estas utilizando? ¿Algun repositorio con el codigo que te da error para probar o testear? Porque probe con NET5/6 y tambien con NET FW 4.8 y me genera [una imagen sin el borde, aquí la imagen que genera con tu codigo](https://imgur.com/a/RBmteH3) ... ademas ([aquí dejo un código de ejemplo en NET6 que utilice para generar la imagen](https://github.com/fernandezja/net6-experiments/tree/main/007-graphics))